# Images Blank on Magento Front End and Backend

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a site that some of the images are appearing blank on the website. There is some images showing but some are missing and just show the Magento image place holder.

I have checked in the back-end where there images are and there is a broken images. I have checked the folders and they are all 777 for the media folders, I have tried a few different browsers also.

I have also done a reindex and cleared both the Magento Cache and Browser Cache

Website is http://www.furnitureplusonline.co.uk/ranges/siena-oak-range.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flat products make sure that the flat product indexer have been run.